# Create byte offset table when writing struct to file

Tags: algorithm, file, struct, rust

Say I have a big struct with branches like in this example:

```
use serde_derive::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use bincode;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::io::SeekFrom;

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct A {
    pub field0: u32,
    pub field1: Vec<B>
}
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct B {
    pub field0: u32,
    pub field1: Cenum,
    pub field2: Vec<C>
}
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct C {
    pub field: Vec<u8>
}
#[derive(Serialize)]
pub enum Cenum {
    Q,
    W
}
fn main() {
    let myvec_len3: Vec<u8> = vec![0xA5,0xA5,0xA5];
    let myvec_len4: Vec<u8> = vec![0xE2,0xE2,0xE2,0xE2];
    let foo = A {
        field0: 0xF0F0F0F0,
        field1: vec![
            B { field0: 0xA0A0A0A0,
                field1: Cenum::Q,
                field2: vec![
                    C { field: myvec_len3.clone() },
                    C { field: myvec_len4.clone() }]}, // VALUE WE WANT
            B { field0: 0xF2F2F2F2,
                field1: Cenum::W,
                field2: vec![
                    C { field: myvec_len3.clone() },
                    C { field: myvec_len4.clone() },
                    C { field: myvec_len3.clone() }]}]};

    let bytes = bincode::serialize(&foo).unwrap();
    let mut f = File::create("byte_dump").unwrap();
    f.write_all(&bytes[..] as &[u8]).expect("Failed to write to file.");
}
```

This program will serialize structure `foo` filled with values and write in binary to a file. If i hex-dump output file `byte_dump` with Linux command `xxd`, this is the output:

```
00000000: f0f0 f0f0 0200 0000 0000 0000 a0a0 a0a0  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0200 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 a5a5 a504 0000 0000 0000 00e2  ................
00000030: e2e2 e2f2 f2f2 f201 0000 0003 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0003 0000 0000 0000 00a5 a5a5 0400  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 e2e2 e2e2 0300 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 a5a5 a5                             .....
```

Hopefully different member values are seen easily this way (e.g. `foo.field0` is first 8 symbols `f0f0 f0f0`, which is equivalent to its value in hex).

Now say we want to get `foo.field1[0].field2[1].field` (marked as VALUE WE WANT comment) out of `byte_dump` file. From hex-dump we know this struct C is located on byte `0x27` right after first `a5a5 a5` sequence and ends right before `f2 f2f2 f2` on byte `0x33`. In total that is 12 bytes of which `04 0000 0000 0000 00` is, what I guess, vector description, and `e2 e2e2 e2` is our value.

To deserialize this sequence, we append following code at the end of our `main()`:

```
    // main() {
    // -snipped-
    let mut f = File::open("byte_dump").unwrap();
    f.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0x27)).unwrap();         // Set current byte to 0x27
    const BR: usize = 12;                           // bytes to read
    let mut bytes: [u8; BR] = [0; BR];              // init buffer
    f.take(BR as u64).read(&mut bytes).unwrap();    // read 12 bytes from current byte

    let bar: C = bincode::deserialize(&bytes).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(bar.field, foo.field1[0].field2[1].field);
    println!("{:X?}", bar.field);    // Success!
}
```

Now, when compiled, hopefully function outputs `[E2, E2, E2, E2]`.

**Question:**

I have used `serde` and `bincode` crates to (de)serialize `foo` structure in this example. But now I would like to automate code which creates a byte offset table of sorts for each instance of struct C in a much much bigger file with more nested struct members. For that I need to store **current byte** and **bytes to read** of each instance of struct C as I am writing serialized `foo` to file.

Now there is functionality for custom (de)serialization functions in `serde`, but I have no clue what kind of algorithm to use, how to begin writing it or if it is even possible to implement with `serde`. How to write serialized struct to file member by member? How to know which byte I am currently on after writing? How to load only a part of file which I want to read to memory? So many questions. So I ask if anyone here has the experience or expertise to help me.

Comment: Have you benchmarked that (de)serializing the entire struct each time is to slow? I can hardly imagine that. If that really is the case, you might be able to realize partial deserialization by providing custom `serde_with` functions forwarding to `bincode::Serializer` after storing the size of individual members returned by `bincode::serialized_size(...)`. Watch out, that you actually use the default parameters and each serde_with is only called once and you handle object layout.

Comment: De serializing data each time right now takes 200 ms, it's too slow for my application. Plus I cannot leave it as is when there is a much more efficient solution insight.
I will look more into `bincode`, thanks

Comment: Just to make sure: You use `cargo run --release`, right? If your struct really is in the MBs, I suspect you might have a `Vec<u8>` /  `&[u8]` or long strings which can be interpreted as such in it? In that case, [serde_bytes](https://github.com/serde-rs/bytes) should speed things up.

Comment: I don't really see a way to get a guaranteed correct solution not relying on internals of bincode here, except implementing an entire `Serializer` and `Deserialzer` forwarding most things to bincode, just additionally storing that indexing information. That's a lot of code, though not necessarily complex.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption of long Vec<u8>. There are thousands of 1 - 10 kB long Vec's. But this program will have to run on an embedded system with limited memory, so data will be stored in Flash memory.
But thanks for help anyway, I am doing some testing right now with custom (de)serialization

Comment: Fixed data types are always better for serialization/deserialization.  
Serializing a `Vec` can be difficult as it has changeable  size.